# ReCaptcha keeps saying im a bot, doesn't ever succeed?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I was using the old ReCaptcha on my site but just upgrading to the new ReCaptcha i've 3-4 different tutorials but it keeps failing and giving the fail error.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="/feedback_sent/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" height="67">
    <tr>
        <td width="30%" height="30">Name</td>
        <td width="70%" height="30">
            <p><input type="text" name="name" size="41"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="30%" height="27">Feedback</td>
        <td width="70%" height="27">
        <textarea rows="8" name="feedback" cols="57"></textarea></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="30%" height="27"></td>
        <td width="70%" height="27">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My_Key"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" colspan="2">
        <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>


</form>
```

PHP:

```
    $secret="---my key---";
    $response=$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $verify=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);

    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo "<p>You are a bot! Go away!</p>";
    }
    else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
            echo "<p>You are not not a bot!</p>";
    }
```

Comment: Use their [API](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/recaptcha/recaptcha-php-1.11.zip), example scripts included.

Comment: Isn't that for the old ReCaptcha? the new one doesn't use the same code as that.

Comment: You are correct, hold on, browsing through my code and grabbing the pieces together.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1:

You will need to create a public and a private key [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin).

### Step 2:

Include [this](https://github.com/google/recaptcha) library to process the information on the server.

### The code:

```
<?php
  $public  = "yourkey";
  $private = "yourkey";
  $lang    = "en";

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(array_key_exists('g-recaptcha-response', $_POST)){
      require 'path/to/recaptcha/autoload.php';
      $c = new ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($private);

      $r = $c->verify(
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"],
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
      );

      if($r->isSuccess()){
        echo 'success';
      } else {
        echo 'failed';
      }
    } else {
      die('client failure, enable js or update browser');
    }
  } else {
    die('form failure');
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>ReCaptcha 2.0</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
      <input for="email" name="email" type="email" required>
      <input for="password" name="password" type="password" required>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?= $public ?>"></div>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=<?= $lang ?>'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will say either `success` or `failed` depending on the input.

Comment: Where do i get autoload.php from?

Comment: If you clicked the link, its in a [sub folder](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/master/src)

Comment: ok thanks i've put it all together but i'm just getting a blank page, it doesn't say "You passed" or "you failed"