# Recaptcha invisible

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm trying to insert google recaptcha invisble. In this mode I saw recaptcha invisble. 
Is it normal ?
I would know if the google recaptcha invisible script is correct or not in this case ? Maybe I forgot an element ?

Thank you

I have this first class
MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA.... == normal v2 recaptcha . this element works perfectly
MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE... =  INVISIBLE RECAPTCHA

Below, this element write the code inside my form.

```
class GoogleRecaptchaDisplay {

    public function execute() {
      $output = '';

      if (!empty(MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY) && MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_STATUS == 'True') {
         $output .= '<div class="col-md-12 g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="' . MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY . '"></div>';
      } elseif (!empty(MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_PUBLIC_KEY) && MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_STATUS == 'True') {
        $output .= '<div class="col-md-12 g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="' . MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_PUBLIC_KEY . '"></div>';
    }

      return $output;
    }
  }
```

In my process this element is verify

```
  class GoogleRecaptchaProcess {

/*
 * Google recaptcha
 * @return $error, false if it's ok, true, if there is an error
 */

    public function execute() {

      if (!empty(MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY) && MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_STATUS == 'True') {
        $secret = MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY;
        $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

        $verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
        $captcha_success = json_decode($verify);

        $error = 'false';

        if ($captcha_success->success === true) {
          $error = 'false';
        } else {
          $error = 'true';
        }
      } elseif (!empty(MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY) && MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_STATUS == 'True') {
        $secret = MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY;
        $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];

        $verify = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={$secret}&response={$response}");
        $captcha_success = json_decode($verify);

        $error = 'false';

        if ($captcha_success->success === true) {
          $error = 'false';
        } else {
          $error = 'true';
        }
      }

      return $error;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've already created an answer to this with [minimal code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41665332/4982088).

Comment: Here is the unofficial google Invisible reCAPTCHA PHP library https://github.com/geordyjames/google-Invisible-reCAPTCHA . Read its documentation first. Hope it will be helpful to you.  One more thing you forgot to add remote IP along with verification URL.