# Increase ReCaptcha expiration time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to increase the google ReCaptcha expiration time? I have tried below one,

```
  <script>
   var callback = function() {
      grecaptcha.render('id-of-render-element', {
         'sitekey': 'your-site-key',
         'expired-callback': expCallback
       });
   };
   var expCallback = function() {
      grecaptcha.reset();
   };
</script>
    <div id="id-of-render-element"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=callback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Taken from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param) _Optional. The name of your callback function to be executed when the recaptcha response expires and the user needs to solve a new CAPTCHA._ based on this I'd imagine it'd have to be `'expCallback'` (a string) instead of a reference to the function

Comment: But i need to increase the expiration time, not to refresh the captacha again to resolve.Is there anyway to solve this problem??

Comment: From the documentation, it doesn’t look like it. And I doubt it would be a good idea on Google’s end to make this possible - because that might have implications on how successful people will be in trying to crack this CAPTCHA using automated tools, or sth. like that.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664877/recaptcha-keeps-saying-im-a-bot-doesnt-ever-succeed/41665332#41665332) for a server sided verification. If successful, store a time in a session and dont print out recaptcha, should be as easy as that.

Answer (score 11):

This has worked for me on both Invisible and the Checkbox versions. I understand you want to "increase" the time, however that is not an option Google offers. I simply reboot the box every 5 min.

```
setInterval(function(){ grecaptcha.reset(); }, 5 * 60 * 1000 ); 
// just reset every 5 min
```

Also, setting the "Advanced" box slider in your Google Developer Console to "least restrictions" seems to help.

Keep in mind with the new "Invisible" Recapcha you may not need to reset or extend the time unless you have additional AJAX validation. I have noticed that when I use the new "invisible" method that the box stays good forever if I only trigger it when the form is validated first.

Q.E.D.
A better solution to the problem might then be simple to use this
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#auto_render

Comment: Not working in Iframe , any solution for that ?

Comment: try storing setInterval into a window var -- 
something like var window.myInterval = setInterval(function, milliseconds);

Answer (score 1):

**Best Solution**

```
<input type='hidden' name='recaptcha_token' id='recaptcha_token'>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{ env("GOOGLE_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY") }}"></script>

<script>
    setInterval(function () { 
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('{{ env("GOOGLE_CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY") }}')    
            .then(function(token) {
                document.getElementById("recaptcha_token").value = token;
            }); 
        });
    }, 30 * 1000);
</script>
```