# How to extend Google reCaptcha expiry time?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Is it possible to adjust Google reCaptcha v3 expiry time?
I looked up Google Documentation and it didn't mention anything about it.
Guidance is much appreciated.

Their site also didn't have any fields to adjust the expiry time.
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

```
echo "<table><tr><td><div id=\"contactform_main\">
<ol><li>
<label for=\"name\" id=\"labamt\">Amount* (Fiat)</label>
<input class=text type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" id=\"amount\">
</li>
<div class=\"g-recaptcha\" id=\"captchaID\" data-sitekey=\"sitekey\" data-callback=\"submitformf1\"></div>
<div id=\"g-captcha-error\"></div>
<li class=\"buttons\" style=\"text-align:center;\">
<input class=\"send\" type=\"button\" id=\"preview\" value=\"Preview\" style=\"float:none; margin:10px;\" onclick=\"javascript:submitformf1()\">
<div class=\"clr\"></div>
</li>



function submitformf1()
{
...
var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
...
if(response==0){
    alert("Please fill captcha");
    return false;
}
...
}
```

Kind Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820652/increase-recaptcha-expiration-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase ReCaptcha expiration time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820652/increase-recaptcha-expiration-time)

Comment: My Apologies, I...don't understand how to integrate their solution into my code...
My captcha will call the submitformf1(). At which junction do I insert the setInterval()?