# reCAPTCHA returns only false and I'm getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE while loading

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

So... I decided to use reCAPTCHA on my website and it returns only false when it's JSON decoding, just like that:

```
$secretKey = "***********";
$responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify? 
        secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$responseKey.'';

$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response);
if ($response->{'succes'} == 'true') {
  $_SESSION['response'] = "succes";
} else {
  $_SESSION['response'] = "fail";
}
```

It always writes "fail"

But when it's not  json decoding:

```
$secretKey = "**************";
$responseKey = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$response = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$responseKey.'');
$_SESSION['response'] = $response;
```

It returns true: `{ "success": true, "challenge_ts": "2018-05-07T19:54:43Z", "hostname": "mywebsite.com" }`

And second problem is that ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error, when I load action page. It occurs only when there's that reCAPTCHA stuff.

My post:

```
<form method="post" id="form" class="form" action="action/logreg.php">
 <input name="name" class="name" placeholder="Jméno" type="text" />
 <input name="surname" class="surname" placeholder="Přijmení" type="text"/>
 <input name="email" class="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="email"  />
 <input name="psswd" class="psswd" placeholder="Heslo"  type="password"/>
 <button type="submit"name="regBtn" class="regBtn">Registrovat</button>
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*********"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReCaptcha keeps saying im a bot, doesn't ever succeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664877/recaptcha-keeps-saying-im-a-bot-doesnt-ever-succeed)

Comment: Also what is `$response->{'succes'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo?

```
if($response->{'succes'} == 'true')
```

It should be *success*.
Also, it's a boolean in the response, not string, so you can't put 'true', use *true* without quotes.

Comment: yep that's it. Thank you very much, but that ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error still occurs sometimes.